# How to add server generated variables to devise sign up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, devise, server

Hello together I try to get two additional variables, which will be generated by the server, to the sign up process of devise.

My registration controller looks like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params
    public_key = 'test123'
    private_key ='private_test123'
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :public_key => public_key, :private_key => private_key)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

But devise do not save the variables public and private_key.
(The Database is set up correctly and contains the two variables)

Do you know how I can fix that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The method `sign_up_params` is only to white list keys which is not default to `devise` so you just need :

```
params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :public_key, :private_key)
```

to white list those 2 varibale. This will not send those two variable to database unless you send those values from the `form` or add it to from devise `create` action from `RegistrationController`.

To get an idea how to override default `create` action see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10118329/4587148)

you don't need these

```
public_key = 'test123'
private_key ='private_test123'
```

in sign_up_params